# Vue.js DOM lag caused by async updates queue when updating component data

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

I have an upload module that loads a lot of files into memory (no actual uploading) and process them using a memory-intensive function. For ~300Mb of files, it will take the processing function approximately 5 seconds to finish.

My processing function has a progress callback which is called at every slice processed, with a floating-point progress indicator as argument. The (simplified) vue.js component looks like this:

**Template (HTML):**

```
<div class="progress" v-bind:style="{ width: progress + '%' }"></div>
```

**Script (ES6):**

```
export default {

  name: 'Dropzone',

  data () {
    return {
      progress: 0
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onDrop (e) {

      let $vm = this;
      let files = e.target.files;

      loadFunction(files, function progressCb (progress) {

        // This lags
        $vm.progress = Math.round(progress * 100);

        // also tried explicit data setting:
        //   $vm.$set('progress', Math.round(progress * 100));

        // also tried manual updating:
        //   document.querySelector('.progress').style.width = Math.round(progress * 100) + '%';
        //   or: $('.progress').css('width', Math.round(progress * 100) + '%');

        // But this works without lag:
        window.document.title = Math.round(progress * 100);


      }, function doneCb () {
        alert('done');
      });

    }
  }

}
```

The `window.document.title` updating **goes smoothly**, linearly from 0 to 100%, whereas the progress bar's behavior is **erratic**, sometimes advancing by steps of 27%, sometimes going straight from 0% to 100% after 5 seconds of waiting.

My understanding of the problem is that the DOM updates are being throttled by [Vue.js' async updates queue](http://012.vuejs.org/guide/best-practices.html#Understanding_Async_Updates) due to the high quantity of operations the Javascript VM has to process while updating the progress bar. How do I circumvent this limitation?

Comment: How does `loadFunction()` work? Is it truly async? are the individual files processes in individual async calls?

I *think* but can't promise (pun not intended), that it would work if you wrapped each file in an individual Promise, wrapped all of them in  `Promise.all()`, and  increased the progress value in each Promises `then()`?

Comment: @LinusBorg Sadly, it is truly async, and makes use of promises internally :( But I'm curious, what do you think would cause the `window.document.title` updating fine when the DOM lags?

Comment: I think your processing is going to need to pause and continue periodically using setTimeout so that the event loop exits for a moment and the browser can spend time on DOM updates.